# How to implement simple REST API proxy server in python

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, caching, proxy-server

I'm trying to build a simple REST API proxy server that receives HTTP requests and forwards them to a remote server.
I need to make it so it is not transparent  which means if the client sends a request and the proxy does not have a response ready in its cache, it will not block the user and instead will return another immediate respond in some format, so that the response could be sent to the client later.
I am trying to use Flask in order to create the server but I don't understand how can I send a response back to the client and later update him with the correct response from the server.
My Idea was to use Flask and whenever I get some request I will initiate a new thread that will send this request to the remote server and when the thread finished it will send the response back to the client.
But What do I send to the client before initiating the thread? I thought of a Future object maybe that I will resolve in the thread, but I don't really know if that is the right way to go about this since I am new to python and server programming.

I would Appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction as to how to implement this proxy server.
Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at a tutorial, like this one https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

Comment: Thanks alot for the fast reply. This helps me with the problem of preforming something in the background which is great! Now I have one more question: I need to support multiple requests at the same time and as I understand it the Flask Module only supports one request at a time. Is there a way around that?

Comment: You should actually look at something like Fast-API instead of flask if your are only planning on using it for API purposes.  Fast-API supports concurrency (async/await) https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/